# Is there a new cycle for $f(n)$ in a "$1 x+3$"-variation of the Collatz-problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, collatz-conjecture

Let $f$ be defined as follows.

$$ f(n) :=
\begin{cases}
n+3         & \text {if $n$ is odd,} \\
\frac{n}{2}   & \text {if $n$ is even.} 
\end{cases}$$

If we start at $n=15$, we get the following sequence by successive applications of $f$:

> 15,18,9,12,6,3,6,3,6…

I found the two following cycles:

> 3,6,3,6,3,6…

and

> 1,4,2,1,4,2…

Is there any other cycle?

Thank you so much!

Comment: $ 4 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 4 $

Comment: Ohh..sorry It must be $f(n)≠1$

Comment: There are no other cycles ... all numbers will fall into one of these two cycles.

Comment: I put $5$ instead of $3$, end up to a loop $\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 8\rightarrow 4\rightarrow 2\rightarrow 1\rightarrow 6\rightarrow 3$

Comment: What do you call "new" ???

Comment: @Yves Daoust I want to find  other cycles.

Comment: @Yves Daoust..Why downvoted my question :(

Comment: @I'mastudent I think the person who downvoted did it because it is badly phrased. I proposed you an edit.

Comment: @Idéophage Now I accept your edit.I missed the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you successively apply $f$ to a value, it must be divided by $2$ at least one step out of two (because when you add $3$, you get an even number). Let $n$ be an odd number strictly greater than $3$. Then $f^2(n) = \frac{n+3}{2} < n$. We continue to apply $f$ until we get an other odd number, which is then strictly less than $n$.

So every number leads to an odd number less than or equal to $3$. The two possibilities are $1$ and $3$, leading to the two only cycles.

Comment: Please prove mathematical .

Comment: Sorry ,this is wrong: $\frac{x+3}{2^n} = x$ because, we dont know "cycle lenth"

Comment: I added a more precise explanation, you are right, that was not a proof.

Answer (score 2):

$$\text{odd}(n)\land n>3\implies \text{even}(n+3)\land n>3\implies n>\frac{n+3}2$$
$$\text{even}(n)\land n>1\implies n>\frac n2$$

hence the sequence is decreasing for all $n$ but possibly $0,1,2,3$.

Then

$$0\to0\to0\to0\to0\to0\cdots$$
$$1\to4\to2\to1\to4\to2\cdots$$
$$2\to1\to4\to2\to1\to4\cdots$$
$$3\to6\to3\to6\to3\to6\cdots$$

For negative $n$, the sequence is increasing both for odd and for even.

Answer (score 0):

For general transformation $a \gt 3, a \text{ is odd}$ we'll have one transformation (with any $k>0$):
$$a=2k+3 \to b=(a+3)/2 = ((2k+3)+3)/2 = k+3 $$

- 1. Result for general transformation

$$ a=2k+3 \to b=k+3 \\ \implies \\ \text{ for all odd $a \gt 3$ each transformation $ a \to b={a+3\over2^A}$decreases}
$$

- 2. Test on existence of short (1-step) cycles:
     $$ a = (a+3)/2^A \\
      a2^A-a = 3 \\
      a = {3 \over 2^A-1 } \\
      \implies a \in \{1,3\} \\
      \implies \text{ cycle $1$: } (1 \to 4 \to 2 \to 1 \to \cdots);\\
     \text{ cycle $2$: } (3 \to 6 \to 3 \to \cdots ) 
     $$
     Since all other $a \gt 3$ decrease (by 1. ) only no more cycle is possible.